# Move and delete a file from two servers

Tags: php, file-io

At work, we have a website on which we publish PDF files which are available for download (mostly user notices etc.). We also manage our internal database for updates and to generate CD's and USB Sticks with all PDF files on it, which are shipped out with the products.
So I build a platform where all plants that produce these PDF files can upload them. From time to time, a person will take care of updating the system (sync both servers).

I would like to have a link next to the files with a delete option. I already have that using a simple php script.

```
<?php 
$deleter = new Deleter("./");
class Deleter {
    var $filename;
        var $ignorelist = array (
        '.',
        '..',
        'index.php',
        'del.php',
        'deletefile.php'
    );
    function Deleter($path="./") {
        $this->__construct($path);
    }
    function __construct($path="./") {

        $this->filename = basename(__FILE__);
        array_push($this->ignorelist, $this->filename);

        // insert page header
        $this->createHeader();

        // condition: create initial file list?
        if (isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])) {

            // a path has been set, escape and use
            $path = basename($_GET['delete']);
            $path = urldecode($path);
            //$path = mysql_real_escape_string($path);

            // condition : Step 2: seek deletion confirmation?
            if (!isset($_GET['confirm']) || $_GET['confirm'] != 'aye') {
                $this->createConfirmationStep($path);

            // step 3: delete!  
            } else {
                $this->createShowDelete($path);
            }

        // step 1: no files selected, create file list  
        } else {
            echo '
                <p>These files are on the server:</p>
                <ul>
            ';
            $this->createFileList($path);
            echo '</ul>';
        }

        // insert page footer
        $this->createFooter();
    }


    /**
     * Step 1: Create a list of all files within a specific directory
     *
     * @param string $path The server path to look for files in 
     * @return array $fileList Array of all files, with file/directory details
     * @access public
     */
    function createFileList($path) {

        // condition : if the path isn't set, assume one
        if (!isset($path)) {
            $path = "./";
        }

        // temporary arrays to hold separate file and directory content
        $filelist = array();
        $directorylist = array();

        // get the ignore list, in local scope
        $ignorelist = $this->ignorelist;

        // Open directory and read contents
        if (is_dir($path)) {

            // loop through the contents (PHP4 compat)
            $dh  = opendir($path);
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) {

                // skip over any files in the ignore list
                if (!in_array($file, $ignorelist)) {

                    // condition : if it is a directory, add to dir list array
                    if (is_dir($path.$file)) {

                        $directorylist[] = array(
                            "path" => $path,
                            "file" => $file,
                            "filetype" => 'directory',
                            "date" => date("M d Y, H:i", filemtime($path.$file."")),
                            "filecount" => $this->countRelevantFiles($path.$file),
                            "filesize" => 0
                        );

                    // file, add to file array
                    } else {

                        $filelist[] = array(
                            "path" => $path,                            
                            "file" => $file,
                            "filetype" => $this->getFileType($path.$file) . " file",
                            "date" => date("M d Y, H:i", filemtime($path.$file."")),
                            "filecount" => 0,
                            "filesize" => $this->getFileSize(filesize($path.$file))
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // merge file and directory lists
        $finalList = array_merge($directorylist, $filelist);

        // loop through each file
        foreach ($finalList as $key => $value) {

            // condition : add trailing slash for directories
            $trailingslash = ($value['filetype'] == 'directory' ) ? '/' : ''; 

            // condition : if it is a directory, display count of subfiles
            if ($value['filetype'] == 'directory') {
                $fileending = ($value['filecount'] == 1) ? 'item' : 'items';
                $filedetails = ' (contains '.$value['filecount'].' '.$fileending.')';

            // else, if it is a file, display file size
            } else {
                $filedetails = ' ('.$value['filesize'].')';
            }


            // create the html for each project
            echo '
                <li class="' . $value['filetype'].'" id="file_' . urlencode($value['file']) . '">
                        <strong>' . $value['file'] . '</strong> / 

                        ';



            echo '

                    <a href="./'.$this->filename.'?delete='.urlencode($value['file'].$trailingslash).'">
                        Delete
                    </a>
                </li>
            ';
        }
    }


    /**
     * count the number of files in a directory, not including the list of ignorable files
     * 
     * @param string $path The server path to look for files in 
     * @return int $count The number of relevant files
     * @access private
     */
    function countRelevantFiles($path, $count = 0) {

        // open the directory
        if (is_dir($path)) {

            // loop through all files, checking if we should count the current one
            $dh  = opendir($path);
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) {

                if (!in_array($file, $this->ignorelist)) {
                    $count++;
                    if(is_dir($path."/".$file)) {
                        $count = $this->countRelevantFiles($path."/".$file, $count);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }

        // return the result
        return $count;
    }



    /**
     * list all sub-files of a directory
     * 
     * @param string $path The server path to look for files in 
     * @return void
     * @access private
     */
    function listFilesToDelete($path) {

        // open the directory
        if (is_dir($path)) {

            // loop through all files, checking if we should count the current one
            $dh  = opendir($path);
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) {

                if (!in_array($file, $this->ignorelist)) {

                    echo '<li>'.$path.'/'.$file.'</li>'; 

                    if(is_dir($path."/".$file)) {
                        $this->listFilesToDelete($path."/".$file);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Delete files
     * 
     * @param string $path The server path to delete
     * @return void 
     * @access private
     */
    function delete($path) {
        // Simple delete for a file
        if (is_file($path)) {

            echo '<li>deleting file: ' . $path . '</li>';

if (copy($path, "../trash/".$path)) {
  unlink($path);
}
        } 

        }




    /**
     * Create a nice readable filesize from the number of bytes in a file
     *
     * @param int $size the size in bytes
     * @param string $retstring 
     *
     * @return string the size in nice words
     */
    function getFileSize($size, $retstring = null)
    {
        $sizes = array('B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');
        if ($retstring === null) { $retstring = '%01.2f %s'; }
        $lastsizestring = end($sizes);
        foreach ($sizes as $sizestring) {
                if ($size < 1024) { break; }
                if ($sizestring != $lastsizestring) { $size /= 1024; }
        }
        if ($sizestring == $sizes[0]) { $retstring = '%01d %s'; } // Bytes aren't normally fractional
        return sprintf($retstring, $size, $sizestring);
    }


    /**
     * Function to find a file type for a given filename
     * 
     * @param string $file filename/path
     * @return string $extension file type
     */
    function getFileType($file="") {

        // get file name 
        $filearray = explode("/", $file);
        $filename = array_pop($filearray);

        // condition : if no file extension, return
        if(strpos($filename, ".") === false) return false;

        // get file extension
        $filenamearray = explode(".", $filename);
        $extension = $filenamearray[(count($filenamearray) - 1)];
        return $extension;

    }



/* Page Building Methods */


    /**
     * Create page header
     */
    function createHeader(){
        echo '

        ';      
    }


    /**
     * Create page footer
     */
    function createFooter(){
        echo '

        ';
    }



    /**
     * Create confirmation step
     */
    function createConfirmationStep($path){
        echo '
            <p><a href="'.$this->filename.'">� back to file list</a></p>
            <p>Please confirm that you want to delete the following files:</p>
            <p class="confirm"><a href="'.$this->filename.'?delete='.$path.'&confirm=aye">Delete</a></p>
            <ol>
                <li>'.$path.'</li>
        ';

        $this->listFilesToDelete($path);

        echo '
            </ol>
            <p class="confirm"><a href="'.$this->filename.'?delete='.$path.'&confirm=aye">Delete</a></p>
        ';
    }



    /**
     * Show the files you're deleting
     */
    function createShowDelete($path){
        echo '
            <p><a href="'.$this->filename.'">� back to file list</a></p>
            <p>The following items have been removed:</p>
            <ol>
        ';

        $this->delete($path);

        echo '
            </ol>
            <p><strong>Deletion complete.</strong></p>
            <p><a href="'.$this->filename.'">� back to file list</a></p>
        ';
    }

}

?>
```

Now what I would like this to do is delete a file on one server e.g. `server1.com/files/` and move the same file from `server2.com/files/` to `server2.com/trash`/

I have full access to both servers. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Your code is very long, no one will not bother to read it all. make your question short and precise.

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't tell us on what OS you're running you php script, I'm assuming you have a linux.
since you need to do that from one server, you'd need to have a [passwordless ssh access](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) to the other server. then you'd need to create a bash script that utilizes `mv` and `rsync` to do the file manipulations you need. and then you can use php's `exec()` function to execute and send the filename param to the shell script from a web page.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to configure rsync over ssh with --delete option. Something like this

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avz --delete /path/files -e "ssh" userforsync@$SECONDARYSERVER:/path/files
```

where is $SECONDARYSERVER is dns name or ip. To make this work you should accept authentication by public key on secondary server and add public key to authorized keys